# A PHP script to let users download a file from my website without revealing the actual file link in my website?

Tags: php, file, scripting, download, hide

The question says it all.

How do I let the users download a file from my website and **not** let them see what link that file comes from?

I understand that there might be a need for something like a *download.php* which will serve as the gateway but past that phase, I dont know what to script next...

If it bothers you to write the whole code, a few function names that I should need to use would be really handy!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Find a way to identify the file to download (for instance, a GET variable that matches the ID of a row in a database, or something along these lines). Make damn sure it's a valid one, because you don't want your users to be able to download anything off your site. Then, use [`header`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) with `Content-Disposition` to tell the browser the file should be downloaded, and [`readfile`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) to output it.

For instance:

```
<?php

$id = intval($_GET['id']);
$query = mysql_query('SELECT file_path FROM files WHERE id = ' . $id);
if (($row = mysql_fetch_row($query)) !== false)
{
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($row[0]));
    readfile($row[0]);
}
exit;

?>
```

Comment: I remember using a similar technique for exporting email addressess in a csv file. The content-type header was ignored by safari for mac.

Comment: Is this script htaccess-proof? I have a htaccess rule to deny the access to real URL in case the method was bypassed. Does `deny from all` affects this script too?

Comment: @CodigosTutoriales, rules in .htaccess files only impact web requests from a client. They don't do anything to prevent your server code from reading files on the server.

Answer (score 4):

You can't make someone download a file from a URL without letting them know the URL.  It's not possible under the HTTP specification.  Anything downloaded has a URL.

You can, however, have a download URL that only works once, or requires some specific information to be passed via the POST method.  You check for a token in the GET or POST variables and invalidate that token once it's used once.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `header()` function which is [documented here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

I would suggest scrolling down and looking at the 1st example. It seems to be doing exactly what you want.

Comment: Just a note for Shedo Chung-Hee Surasi - The second example also shows you how you can specify a filename that is different from the name of the original file (as you mentioned in your question).

Answer (score 0):

[readfile](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) should do what you want.  Put the actual file outside the web server root, and require some credentials before passing back the file.